# Down key behaviour when tabbing in Komodo Edit 7

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I recently upgraded to Komodo Edit 7 from v6. In previous versions if I was adding tabs to the beginning of lines I could press down and the cursor would automatically move to the beginning of the next line. The net effect meant that to indent a whole bunch of line I just had to press DOWN and TAB repeatedly

Since I've upgraded it no longer works like this. If I press TAB at the beginning of a line and then down, it indents the first line, then moves to the next line, one tab width in.

Does anyone know how to re-enable this functionality on Komodo Edit 7, or whether it was completely removed?

Comment: An alternate procedure is to hold SHIFT, move DOWN repeatedly to highlight all the lines, then press TAB to indent the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issue.  As Paul Sweatte suggests, there is an alternate way to indent a group of lines (adding tabs at the beginning), but no alternative exists for doing this in the middle of a group of lines.

I have submitted a bug here: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=94104

**Update:** Bug status has been updated to Resolved.  This should be fixed in the next release (7.1.0) or you can download the nightly build: http://downloads.activestate.com/Komodo/nightly/

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also submitted it as a bug at http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=93681 but thanks for letting me know it had been resolved!